# reloading dragula plugin not working

Tags: jquery, dragula

Using dragula PLugin for drag & drop

https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/

implemented it but in few case after the ajax call, i am reloading few portions of the div, and then dragula stops working

how do I can reinitialize it

making it work like this:

```
var drake = dragula($('.container').toArray());
drake.on('drop', function (el, target) {
    $.ajax({success:function(data) {
        $("#reload").load('abc.php?new=' + Math.random() + '&id=' + id,'#reload');      
    });
});
```